# "People icons" in city window

Tags: freeciv

Where can I find a description of "people icons" in the top left corner of city window?

[image: Freeciv city window: citizen/specialist icons]

I guess it has something to do with workers/specialists, but I wasn't able to find it in Game Manual in Wiki pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Happy citizen icons] Happy citizens

[image: Content citizen icons] Content citizens

[image: Unhappy citizen icons] Unhappy citizens

[image: Angry citizen icons] Angry citizens

### Specialists

[image: Entertainers icons] Entertainers

[image: Scientists icons] Scientists

[image: Taxmen icons] Taxmen

[image: Workers icons] Workers

[image: Farmers icons] Farmers

[image: Merchants icons] Merchants

Note: Some of these specialists may not be available in your game. It depends on the ruleset you are playing. For example, the classic ruleset only has entertainers, scientists and tax collectors (taxmen).

In your screenshot, there are three happy citizens, two content citizens, and a scientist.

Sources from Freeciv 2.6.2:

- [data/misc/small.png](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/data/misc/small.png)
- [data/misc/small.spec](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/data/misc/small.spec)
- [data/misc/specialists.png](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/data/misc/specialists.png)
- [data/misc/specialists.spec](https://github.com/freeciv/freeciv/blob/R2_6_2/data/misc/specialists.spec)